# Plotting excel data rows in matplotlib

Tags: python, excel, pandas, rows, keyerror

I have data in an excel file where I need to plot two rows. The excel file has the years in one row, and all the countries in one column ´. The data looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx77A.png)

When trying to plot it I get this key error:

File pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206 in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'TIME'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File ~\OneDrive - Danmarks Tekniske Universitet\Courses\Enviromental Modelling\Assigment 0\Assignment 0.py:22 in 
x = CO2emission['TIME']

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505 in **getitem**
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623 in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'TIME'

---

My code looks like this:

'''

```
`import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing data

studentlist = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\cabu\OneDrive - Danmarks Tekniske Universitet\Courses\Enviromental Modelling\Assigment 0\classlist12104.csv",';') #putting r before the string converts it to raw string
ExcelEmission = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\cabu\OneDrive - Danmarks Tekniske Universitet\Courses\Enviromental Modelling\Assigment 0\eurostat_CO2_emissions.xlsx") 

# Import excel file
CO2emission = pd.read_excel(ExcelEmission, 'Sheet 1',skiprows = 3) # Read specific sheet in the excel file and skipping the first few rows

CO2emission.head()
# Plotting CO2 emission for Denmark


x = CO2emission['TIME']
y = CO2emission['Denmark']`
```

Anyone knows what goes wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73542139/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: Please post the error and code as text, not an image.

Comment: I'm guessing your dataframe is not imported correctly, KeyError means that it's not a column, what happens when you print the dataframe? or the columns?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.